# Drop shadow on face in RealityKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

The task is to show glasses shadow on the user's face. Right now there is no shadow under the glasses. AnchorEntity(.face) is being used as the main anchor for glasses!

How it works now:

[image]

How it should work:

[image]

Comment: There isn't enough information therefor anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Added example photos

Answer (score 0):

**Limited Raytracing options for glass**

In RealityKit 2.0 there are very limited [raytracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)) options for transparent and semi-transparent objects (like glasses, vases or windows). There are no properties that control how raytracing should work. Remember, RealityKit's renderer isn't the same as Arnold in Autodesk Maya, for example. So there are no robust semi-transparent shadows behind glasses in RealityKit. Only frames cast opaque shadows, but these shadows are insignificant, barely noticeable.

**Solution I**

Here is a first solution for this situation - you need to use [baked shadows](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/scriptable-render-pipeline/baked-shadows/) (**fake shadows**) on the texture of a canonical face mesh. But, of course, using this approach, you can't "cast" shadows on real-user eyes to get a **robust shading experience**.

**Solution II**

To shade real-user eyes and areas around eyes in AR app you need to create two alpha-channel masks to apply a lower intensity for eyes and areas around them. For changing intensity of certain areas of background video you need to use compositing methods ([CI filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html)) available in `CoreImage` framework.